# Equivalence Relation Question - Type

Tags: equivalence-relations

Consider the relation $R = \{(x, x) : x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ on $\mathbb{Z}$. Is $R$ reflexive? Symmetric?
Transitive? If a property does not hold, say why. What familiar relation is this?

I think all of these properties are satisfied so it's an equivalence relation. It has to be reflexive as $x\mathrel{R}x$ is true for all $x$ integers. I also think it is symmetric and transitive.

What familiar relation is this? I would say it's an equivalence relation but I think they are searching for a more precise answer. I was also thinking of saying it is the set of all integer coordinates in the $x$-$y$ plane, but I don't think this is correct.

Comment: You might ask yourself, for instance, What integers are related to $3$?

Comment: It's the standard equivalence relation on integers: every integer is equal to itself and unequal to every other integer.

Comment: It is the "*equality*" relation, pure and simple or "*identity*" relation.  The relation is written with the symbol "$=$" or "$i$" or similar.  The equality relation is indeed an equivalence relation and is reflexive, symmetric and transitive (*recall that in definition for transitivity when we talk about $(aRb~\wedge ~bRc)\implies aRc$ we do not require that $a,b,c$ be distinct*)